# How to add items to a list in C# using a class containing public variables

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, list

I hope you can help out a fellow programmer. Basically, I want the user input from the Rich Text Box (taskNameRTB) to be assigned to the `taskName;` string variable in my class `taskStructure` which is in `form1` shown below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class taskStructure
    {
        public string taskName;
        public string taskDescription;
        public int Priority;
        public string dateAndTime;
    }

    public List<taskStructure> TasksArray = new List<taskStructure>(); //Declared a list data structure
```

In my second form which is where the user enters everything related to the task, I want to send this information to the list after the 'Create Task' button has been clicked:

```
 private void createTaskBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 welcomeForm = new Form1();
        welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskName = taskNameRTB.Text;
        welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text;
    }
```

However, when I do this I get a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and I do not understand why. I have also tried these:

```
        welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].Add(taskDescRTB.Text);
        welcomeForm.TasksArray.Insert(0, taskNameRTB.Text);
        welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(taskDescRTB.Text);
        taskNameRTB.Text = welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskName;
```

But the ones that run come up with the same error `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and some of them don't work, such as:

```
welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].Add(taskDescRTB.Text);
```

I'm aware that the list has not been initialized, but how can I initialize it when it doesn't allow me to initialize it with user input...

Any light you can shed on this will be really helpful

Kind Regards,

Kieran

Comment: You haven't populated the list - it's empty. You need to add a reference to a new `taskStructure`, e.g. `TasksArray.Add(new taskStructure())`. I would also advise against using public fields, and also against using nested types unless you really need to. Oh, and read up on .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was hoping to populate the list with the inputs the user enters on my `addTask` form. The reason I used public was so I could access them from different forms as I want to display the tasks the user enters and all their fields (Name, Description of Task etc.) on Form1. Thank you for your advice and help though, I really appreciate it, I've only been programming for a few months, thus not very experienced.

Comment: @KieranLowe rather than use public fields, you should use public properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new `taskStructrue` to the list.

```
welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new taskStructure 
    {
        taskName = taskDescRTB.Text,
        taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text
    });
```

But personally I'd rewrite that class to follow naming conventions and to use properties instead of public fields.

```
public class TaskStructure
{
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string DateAndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you have done and no errors have occured, now that it is added, how would I display what the user has just entered?

I have tried `MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray);` as a test, but can't seem to get it to work. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(welcomForm.TasksArray[0].taskName)` if you want to display the task name.  But depending on were you use that code you might want to check that `TasksArray` has at least one value first, or maybe use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works!  If a user enters another task let's say, would I change [0] to [1]? Or would adding a new task after previously adding one overwrite the first one?

Comment: Adding a new value to a list will increase the size of the list and you would use the `[1]` indexer to get the second value.  But note that when working with lists you typically use loops (`for` or `foreach`) or Linq to work with the data rather than directly using the indexer with a hard coded value.

Comment: I have tried that but it gave me the same exception problem, I redid the code you told me in your answer and now it works, however, the inputted values are the same for both [0] and [1]. Do I have to increment or something to get it to move onto the next one once a task has been entered? Plus thank you for the advice!

Comment: It's hard to say what your new issue is without seeing the code.  I suggest asking a new question if you are having further problems.

Comment: Okay thankyou, I will do that if I can't try myself to fix it. Basically, after they enter the task, it then saves to the list. If they want to add another task, I don't want it to overwrite the first task they entered. So I entered another task, but instead doing MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.tasksArray[1].taskName); to see if the new task registers, however this line of code the ArgumentOutOfRange exception happens again. So I did another
welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new taskStructure { taskName = taskDescRTB.Text, taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text }); but it overwrites the first task.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new taskStructure(taskDescRTB.Text));
```

I don't know what taskStructure is, but you need to fill TasksArray with types of it.

Comment: I have tried that but it says it 'does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments'

Furthermore, I want to specifically assign the input of taskDescRTB.Text to the 'taskName' variable in the 'taskStructure' class

Answer (score 1):

Your TaskStructure is a class, and you are putting all TaskStructure objects into a list,

```
public List<taskStructure> TasksArray = new List<taskStructure>(); //Declared a list data structure
```

Does your Form1() have a constructor that calls InitializeComponents()?

If so, you could **try adding `TasksArray = new List<taskStructure>()`** right below InitializeComponents(), because it looks like you're trying to access the list data structure that hasn't been initialized with new.

**Alternatively**

As another user noted, you can create a constructor class for TaskStructure like this:

```
public TaskStructure(RTB rtb1, rtb2, rtb3) //where RTB is the rich text box type
{
   taskName = rtb1.text;
   taskDescription = rtb2.text;
   //and so on.
}
```

Then you can do TaskArray.add(new TaskStruture(rtb1,rtb2,rtb3).

**Thrid Edit**

Just realized your TaskArray is actually a List,  <s>which in C# (and Java), you cannot access it with an index like TaskArray[0], you have to use getter and setter methods, which in this case is TaskArray.add(), and TaskArray.get(0), you're getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException because you're trying to access a List using square indexes like this --> [0].</s>  You can actually access a list doing list[1](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list), as pointed out by another user.

[Here's a good tutorial on C# lists, by DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

Comment: Yeah my Form1 does have a constructor that calles that.

I have added that but also still get the same error, thanks for trying though, really appreciate it!

Comment: @KieranLowe I just realized, why are you doing TaskArray[0]? C# lists can be simply accessed by doing TaskArray.Add() I think the TaskArray[0] throws the argument error exception, I'm pretty sure!

Comment: Basically, I did that because I want the user to be able to create more than one task, therefore, when they add a new task, it can be [1], [2] etc. and then output them onto Form1() using their index to display each task.

Comment: @KieranLowe just updated my answer, see edits :) basically [1] [2] are for actual arrays declared for example as string[] strArray. You want to use add(0) and get(0) instead

Comment: Ah okay, I seem to be getting slight confused :P I will give what you have mentioned a try and will definitely read the link you gave; I really appreciate your help and time, thank you!

Comment: @KieranLowe if you need further explanation on my explanation do ask here, hope you resolve your issue! If you do don't forget to mark the question answered, and welcome to SO!

Comment: `welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
                {
                    taskName = taskNameRTB.Text,
                    taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text
                });`

I have added what @juharr has advised me and the error no longer happens, I'm just trying to get it to display what the user has entered but having problems with now trying to display it in a MessageBox for a test! I'm currently going through each and every answer to find a resolution, I really appreciate all your time! And thank you! :D

Comment: ...the heck? Why are you saying that C#'s indexer syntax (`list[0]`) doesn't work with `List<T>`? I can assure you it does.

Comment: @JoeWhite my bad, just tested it, sorry for the confusion, I'll update my post. Just been too used to using get and add.